# How I restore Apache to a usable state from a time machine backup?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, apache-http-server, time-machine

I have just restored a time machine backup to a new Macbook Pro. Everything seems to work fine apart from Apache. I am a PHP developer so have a custom setup but use the stock apache install with a newer version of PHP.

After the restore, Apache will not start (there are lots of segmentation faults in the error log e.g child pid 4201 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

PHP is not enabled in httpd.conf on the new machine (my vhost conf files do not seem to have been copied over either - same for the /etc/hosts file) which seems to suggest that this is nothing to do with PHP.

My next step was going to be to do a carbon copy clone of the drive and restore that but I'm wondering if there is some way I can just fix Apache. Does anyone know what might be causing this or how to resolve?

**UPDATE**

Old machine - MacBookPro5,1 - Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869)
New Machine - MacBookPro8,2 - Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J4139)

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 20 2011 22:51:23
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: Another update - I did a 'apachectl configtest' which displayed an error with a file included at the end of httpd.conf relating to entropy - a PHP package I didn't think I was using anymore. I am now trying a fresh install of php via brew.

Comment: This is now resolved. I installed entropy again from here http://taracque.hu/php5/ and everything is working now.

Comment: Well, my theory didn't pan out, and it's comforting to know that Time Machine didn't let your restore downgrade your build of Mac OS X v10.6.7 from the 10J4139 build that the new hardware in your MacBookPro8,2 requires to the older 10J869 build that legacy machines all got as a software update.

You should submit your resolution as an Answer and then accept it once the SU site software lets you do so.

I'm going to delete my Answer since it would probably be more of a red herring than helpful to most people.